# How to redirect user after session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-security

How can i redirect user after session timeout? I have found some solutions but my problem is a little different. I got only one page and when the user clicks a button after timeout, he will be redirected to login page. Is there any solution?

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

set session timeout in your web.xml - and config [spring secruity as you want it](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/sample-apps.html).

Comment: yes, the webapge needs to interact wth server to "trigger" the timeout- you might want to do a fancy async javascript to keep polling server.